# How to use config.ssh.forward_env in Vagrant?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, environment-variables

I want certain environment variables from my host system to be visible inside my Vagrant VM, using the [`config.ssh.forward_env`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) setting. I'm using Vagrant 1.8.1. Here's my Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
  config.ssh.forward_env = ['FOO']
end
```

After creating it, I ran these commands:

```sh
vagrant up
export FOO=bar
vagrant ssh -c 'echo $FOO'
```

I expected the final line to output `bar`, but instead it outputs a blank line (followed by `Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

*TL;DR*

```
fhenri@machine$ export LC_MYVAR=TEST
fhenri@machine$ vagrant ssh -c 'echo $LC_MYVAR'
TEST
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
fhenri@machine$
```

As said in the doc, `config.ssh.forward_env` works as `sendEnv` so to pass variables using sendEnv you must configure your host to accept env variables, by default (and hoping my example above should work) the common setup allows `LC_*` through, you can review the authorized variables in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

you can add your own variables here as needed or use default prefix LC_

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your question directly as you say you want to use `config.ssh.forward_env` but you can actually send environment variables without that like so:

```sh
a=1
vagrant ssh -- -t <<EOF
echo a=$a
EOF

# prints:
a=1
```

What happens here is the variable `$a` gets replaced by `1` and then only the heredoc (the part between `<<EOF` and `EOF`) gets sent to the vagrant VM.

It's maybe obvious to some, but it wasn't to me in the beginning. If you want to make the value of `$a` available in a script you're calling inside the heredoc, then you need to assign it first to a variable and export that variable:

```sh
a=1
vagrant ssh -- -t <<EOF

export b="$a"
c="$a"

bash -c 'echo b=\$b c=\$c'
EOF

# prints:
b=1 c=
```

This trick is valid with "plain" ssh too.