# Shell environment variables in vagrant files are only passed on first up

Tags: shell, vagrant, environment-variables

I'm running Vagrant 1.8.5, which supports [environment variables in the Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#env) at provisioning time using a format like this

> config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", env:
>   {"MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"=>"django",
>   "MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"=>"supersecretpasswordwasreplaced"}

However, I would like these environment variables to also be available when I do `up` without provisioning, or when I SSH into the server to do jobs. The obvious ways I can find are

- to have them built into the box (seems like overkill) or
- [repeat them](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) in my `config.ssh.forward_env` so that they are available to both the provisioner and SSH.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first glance, this answer seems similar to the top voted answer.  However, please look carefully at the redirection operator on the second `echo`

```
config.vm.provision "shell", env: {"DOCKERHUBID"=>ENV['DOCKERHUBID'], "DOCKERHUBPASS"=>ENV['DOCKERHUBPASS']}, inline: <<-SHELL
echo "export DOCKERHUBID=$DOCKERHUBID" > /home/vagrant/.profile
echo "export DOCKERHUBPASS=$DOCKERHUBPASS" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
SHELL
```

Comment: Thank you! There are so many incorrect and confusing answers out there for how to accomplish this. Yours is neither. :)

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure about the best ultimate way - I've seen this question popping from time to time and discussion.

> repeat them in my config.ssh.forward_env so that they are available to both the provisioner and SSH.

well, it could sound like a good solution but there's some drawback, I've discussed [in this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122348/how-to-use-config-ssh-forward-env-in-vagrant)

Personally when I need to set env variable, I would add them in the `.profile` file:

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "export MYSQL_DB_USERNAME = django" > /home/vagrant/.profile
    echo "export MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD = supersecretpasswordwasreplaced" > /home/vagrant/.profile
  SHELL
```

They will be available when you login.

Comment: for whatever reason, I'm using Vagrant 1.8.5 too and no matter what, appending a string to a file does not work :(

Comment: @JeandersonBarrosCândido this is weird and I dont think it has to do with vagrant but might be bash related. if you ssh into the box and run the command, does it work ?

Comment: yes... I just destroyed my vagrant box and created it again... apparently I forgot to rerun vagrant provision ;)

Comment: This script fragment is clearly incorrect and the upvoters have not thought about it or tested it